# Populate Rails Form With Model Information From Another Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**I've renamed the SessionsController and Session Model to Periods/Period because it conflicted with Devise and so you'll see this in the update**

I have a sessions and events model/controller. When a new session is created, it needs to be associated with a particular event.

In my sessions model, I have an event_id, but I want to have a dropdown on the form that is populated with name of non-past events. Once that is selected, the form should be able to assign the correct event_id to the created session.

What is the correct way to go about doing this?

Here is my schema.rb to help you get a clearer picture of what the Models look like:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120807154707) do

  create_table "events", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "date"
    t.string   "street"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "sessions", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",               :default => "",    :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",  :default => "",    :null => false
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",       :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
    t.boolean  "admin",               :default => false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true

end
```

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@period)  do |f| %>


  <%= f.label :Name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name%>

  <%= f.label :Event %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:period, :event_id, Event.all, :id, :name)%>


  <%= f.label :time %>
  <%= f.text_field :time, id: "timepicker" %>

  <%= f.submit "Create Event" %>

<% end %>
```

and I keep getting the following error: `undefined method`merge' for :name:Symbol`

Breaking out the various arguments of collection select: `f.collection_select(:period, :event_id, Event.all, :id, :name)`

```
:period -> The object
:event_id -> the method I want to set on the object.
Event.All -> The collection (for now I'll take all of them)
:id -> the value of the html element option
:name -> the value displayed to the user
```

Am I doing that correct?

Comment: See, below. In short you need to use collection_select without the "f" object and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a select menu with options from another model (not another controller), try [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select).

In your new Session form, this might look like:

```
collection_select(:event, :id, Event.where("date > :date", date: Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
```

In the Sessions controller, in the `create` action, build the association like this:

```
@session.event = Event.find(params[:event][:id])
```

Comment: This got me pointed in the right direction. I know I need to use collection_select, but I don't have it working quite yet. See update for more info.

Comment: Still don't have the form working by filtering out past dates, BUT by removing the f.collection_select, I'm able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this structure works for me:

```
    <%= f.label :event %>
        <%= f.collection_select :event_id, Event.all, :id, :name, {:prompt=> "Pick an Event"}, {:class => "form-control"} %>
```

The last bit was the html part which I used to set the Bootstrap class.

`:name` here could be `:date` or `:street` etc...